# Camera timer animation on UWP

Tags: animation, timer, uwp

I am developing an UWP application, and one of my page is actually for user to take photo of them. In the page, I have timers for user to select before they take picture.

However, I wish to have a timer shown, counting down in the camera screen, so that the user know how much time is left for them to prepare, before the picture is taken.

Any idea on how I can do that? Thank you!

Just in case it is needed, here is my codes for the timers and the take picture buttons:

```
private async void PhotoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //If preview is not running, no preview frames can be acquired
        if (!_isPreviewing) return;

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_seconds));
        await TakePhotoAsync();
        await GetPreviewFrameAsSoftwareBitmapAsync();

        PreviewFrameBackground.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }

private void Timer_3sec_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer_5sec.Opacity = 0.2;
        Timer_7sec.Opacity = 0.2;
        Timer_3sec.Opacity = 1.0;
        _seconds = 3;


    }
    private void Timer_5sec_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer_3sec.Opacity = 0.2;
        Timer_7sec.Opacity = 0.2;
        Timer_5sec.Opacity = 1.0;
        _seconds = 5;

    }

    private void Timer_7sec_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer_3sec.Opacity = 0.2;
        Timer_5sec.Opacity = 0.2;
        Timer_7sec.Opacity = 1.0;
        _seconds = 7;

    }
```

Comment: What about a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have never used DispatcherTimer before... is it possible if you show a simple demo? I will be really grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) to solve your problem. 
Here a little code sample how you can do that (The sample dont show how to take the capture or to show the remaining seconds, just to calculate them!)

Class-Parameters:

```
private int _startTime;
private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
```

Methods:

```
private void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            _startTime = Environment.TickCount;
            _timer.Start();
        }

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            var remainingSeconds = _seconds - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount - _startTime).Seconds;

            if(remainingSeconds <= 0)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                _timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
                timerText.Text = "0 Seconds";
                //Capture Image
            } else
            {
                timerText.Text = "" + remainingSeconds + " Seconds";
            }

        }
```

You need to call the `StartTimer`-Method in you Click-Methods, after setting the `_seconds`.

Comment: Thank you so much! But, how do I show the remaining seconds? That is the main reason I posted this question...

Comment: Either you make picutres with the remaining seconds and load them in oyur preview Area or you make a textbox, where you display them

Comment: Do I write it like this for textblock? timer.Text = remainingSeconds.ToString();

Comment: You dont need the ToString(). You can do it like that: timer.Text = ""+ remainingSeconds + " Seconds", or something like that

Comment: My bad... The calculation of the remaining seconds was swapped... See my edited answer